# AWS ECS vs EKS for hybrid cloud strategy

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecs, eks

What can EKS deployment do that ECS deployment can't do? is there any specific circumstances that you have to deploy your application on EKS but not ECS.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of general positioning [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-ecs-vs-amazon-eks-making-sense-of-aws-container-services/) may be a good starting point.

Given in the title you mention "hybrid" deployments you may be interested in investigating and investigating [ECS Anywhere](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-amazon-ecs-anywhere/) and [EKS Anywhere](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/eks-anywhere/). They are both coming in 2021.